# Spring : How to retrieve set of entities using JpaRepository method without using the primary key?

Tags: java, mysql, maven, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I want to retrieve list of entities for a given id from my database. But this id is not the primary key of my table.

```
public List<Notification> view(ApplicationUser applicationUser){
    List<Notification> notification = repository.findAll();  

    return notification;
}
```

In my code I have a applicationUser ID which is NOT the primary key of notification table. It is only a foreign key. In the above case I can retrieve the entire table. I tried repository.getOne() method as well. but my requirement can not be full filled with that.

I want to get all the entities to the notification list where appliclationUserId field of my table is equal to the user provided value.

Here is my notification table

```
CREATE TABLE `notification` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  `message` varchar(100),
  `dateAndTime` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `read` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `notificationType` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
  `userId` bigint(20),
  FOREIGN KEY (`userId`) REFERENCES `application_user` (`id`)
);
```

Any help is highly appreciated.z

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Repository class:

```
 @Query("select nt from notification nt where nt.userId = ?1") 
  List<Notification> findByUserId(BigInteger userId);
```

Call:

```
repository.findByUserId(BigInteger.valueOf(applicationUser.getId());
```

Comment: I did it like this. But not working 
public interface NotificationRepository extends JpaRepository<Notification, Long> {

    @Query("select nt from notification nt where nt.userId == ?1")
    List<Notification> findByUserId(ApplicationUser applicationUser);
}

Comment: Ah. Now I understand your question.
Try this
`@Query("select nt from notification nt where nt.userId == ?1") List<Notification> findByUserId(int userId);` 

Call: `repository.findByUserId(applicationUser.getId(())`

Comment: Please provide them to us. Otherwise we can't help you.

Comment: That was because using == instead of =

Comment: So this solution is now working? Then mark the question as solved please.

Comment: No still not working. In my database userId is a bigInt. Here I am using long. So error occurred

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154847/discussion-between-waize-and-sandu-prass).